# Marshalling unique_ptr

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pointers

I have a c++ struct that is as follows:

```
struct Stuff {
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> data;
};
```

How would I marshal this into C# without converting the unique_ptr to a raw pointer in c++?

Thanks

Comment: What would you want to do with it in c#, it only deals with raw pointers

Comment: @pm100 I'm saving data from C++ into c#